# rqt_bag: cannot import name qInfo

Tags: ros, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Today `rqt_bag` doesn't want to work. Giving me this error:

```
$ rqt_bag
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rqt_bag", line 5, in <module>
    from rqt_bag.bag import Bag
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/bag.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .bag_widget import BagWidget
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/bag_widget.py", line 40, in <module>
    from python_qt_binding.QtCore import Qt, qInfo, qWarning, Signal
ImportError: cannot import name qInfo
```

I am running ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ros just got updated today morning with `apt upgrade`.

Any idea how can I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274739/rqt_bag:-cannot-import-name-qinfo/) by [Yousof](https://answers.ros.org/users/29342/yousof/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-11-01

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please read the comments for more information about the resolution of this bug

---

### Temporary fix

Edit the file:

```
sudo nano /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/bag_widget.py
```

Modify the line producing the error from:

```
from python_qt_binding.QtCore import Qt, qInfo, qWarning, Signal
```

To

```
from python_qt_binding.QtCore import Qt, qWarning, Signal
```

Then comment every call to `qInfo` in the code, you can find them with:

```
grep -rn "qInfo" /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/
```

Use nano or any other editor to comment the calls inside this python code.

You can then use `rqt_bag` again!

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guilherme Schvarcz Franco](https://answers.ros.org/users/27542/guilherme-schvarcz-franco/) on 2017-11-08**:
Works as a charm. Tks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-08**:
Note that as @VictorLamoine already writes: this is really a *temporary fix*. As soon as you receive an updated `.deb` (through `apt-get update` fi) the changes will be overwritten.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-08**:
Bug where this is tracked: [ros-visualization/rqt_bag#15](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_bag/issues/15).

And PR that (presumably) fixes it: [ros-visualization/rqt_bag#16](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_bag/pull/16).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-08**:
And a PR that fixes the previous PR: [ros-visualization/rqt_bag#17](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_bag/pull/17).

To quote @Dirk Thomas:

> `rqt_bag` version 0.4.11 will fix the problem. I have just released that version so it might be a bit until it is available from Debian packages.

**Comment by [Marvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/32593/marvin/) on 2017-11-12**:
For me, the temporary fix allows rqt_bag to start; however, attempting to load a bag file results in the same qInfo error.  (Ubuntu 16.04, Kinetic)

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-11-13**:
@Marvin make sure you have done the last steps (`grep` + edit the file)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-13**:
Another option is to enable the [Shadow Repository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) and install `rqt` and related pkgs from there. Don't forget to switch back to the default repository after doing that.

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2017-12-01**:
I tried @VictorLamoine temporary fix and it worked for me, thanks